# UIView Position

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

How to detect the position of a uiview after applying the CGAffineTransformRotate to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set view's background color to check actually where view is going after transformation. If view will be out of display area then this trick will not help you. otherwise you can calculate view's new origin using below function.

`newPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(initialPoint, customTransform);`

pass view's origin in initial point and your transform in customtrasform

Comment: @Armmaan : Your trick not work for me!  here is my code what m did as your trick ,I m getting the new point as (0,0) with this :       newPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(self.bounds.origin,transform);           
I applied the CGAffineTransformation to uiview in touchesMoved metohd as follows :
[self setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, [self degreesToRotateObjectWithPosition:self.bounds.origin andTouchPoint:[touch locationInView:self.superview] andRotateClockWise:YES])];